# JavaScript bitwise undefined pitfalls?

Tags: javascript, undefined, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior

What is the logic of bitwise operators on undefined???

```
var x;
console.log(x);     // undefined
console.log(x^7);   // 7
console.log(7^x);   // 7
console.log(x|7);   // 7
console.log(7|x);   // 7
console.log(7&x);   // 0
console.log(x&7);   // 0
console.log(~x);    // -1
console.log(x*2);   // NaN
console.log(x/2);   // NaN
console.log(x+2);   // NaN
console.log(x-2);   // NaN
```

I can see some sense in NaN. Because undefined -2 is really 'not a number'. But I do not follow any logic on bitwise operators and undefined.

Comment: Bit operations only make sense on integers, so the arguments are automatically coerced to that type.

Comment: Yes, I expected it would throw an error or something meaningful. That silent coercion made infinite loop in my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The internal function [`[ToInt32]`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) is called on *all* operands for *all* bitwise operators.

Note that `ToInt32(undefined) -> 0` and the range is `[0, 2^32)`